# system.xml <frontend_model> resolve to wrong path

Tags: magento-1.9

i have system.xml as follow:

```
                    <export translate="label">
                        <label>Export</label>
                        <frontend_model>velajne_adminhtml/system_config_form_field_exportjne</frontend_model>
                        <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </export>
```

and config.xm as follows:

```
    <models>
        <velajne>
            <class>Vela_Jne_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>velajne_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </velajne>
        <velajne_adminhtml>
            <class>Vela_Jne_Model_Adminhtml</class>
        </velajne_adminhtml>
        <velajne_shipping>
            <class>Vela_Jne_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>velajne_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </velajne_shipping>
```

Why does it produce errors like this

```
Warning: include(Mage\Velajne\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Exportjne.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in D:\WWW\Domains\magentodev.local\htdocs\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
```

It seems that it can't resolve velajne_adminhtml correctly.
if i use just velajne or velajne_shipping it resolved correctly.

Comment: The file in the warning does not appear to match the file defined in the backend_model. Is this really the part causing the error?

Comment: yep it is. it doesn't resolve backend_model correctly.
it should resolve to

Vela\Jne\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Exportjne.php

Comment: i just found the answer, frontend_model resolve to Blocks (instead of Models) and i dont have this Blocks definition in my config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer,
frontend_model resolves to Blocks (instead of Models) and i didnt have this Blocks definition in my config.xml that's why it produced error.

Adding velajne_adminhtml to my config.xml -> global -> blocks fixed the problem

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <velajne>
            <class>Vela_Jne_Block</class>
        </velajne>
        <velajne_adminhtml>
            <class>Vela_Jne_Block_Adminhtml</class>
        </velajne_adminhtml>
```

Comment: please mark this as accepted.